# Получить доступ к соседям this

Tags: jquery

```
<ol>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ol>

<script>
$('li').click(function () {
   $(this); // Например клик по li 2
});
<script>
```

Например, пользователь кликнул по li **2**, возможно ли при клике по li, работать с соседями li, в данном случае **1** и **3**? Если да, то как получить к ним доступ?

Идентификаторов у li нет. Есть только **ol** и внутри **li**. **ol** на странице несколько. Разрешается присвоить только идентификатор объекту **ol**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('li').click(function() {
  /*var $lis = $(this).siblings(); // only the other two
  console.log($lis.length);
  $lis = $(this).closest("ol").find('li'); // all three
  console.log($lis.length);*/

  // только соседние
  console.log("previous", $(this).prev().length, $(this).prev().text());
  console.log("next", $(this).next().length, $(this).next().text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: closest получает последний элемент. Получается если в **ol** 5 li, то я получаю не соседний(3), а пятый **li**

Comment: @ДенисНебесный Это Вы где взяли такую инфорамцию? `closest` находит ближайший элемент в цепочке родителей `this`, удовлетворяющий селектору.

Comment: Убедитесь в этом сами  https://codepen.io/denis-nebesnyj/pen/XQabOE

Comment: @ДенисНебесный В чем я должен убедиться? `alert($lis.length);` показывает *количество* элементов `li` под тем же родителем.

Comment: При нажатии на любой элемент возвращает последний

Comment: @ДенисНебесный Прочитайте еще раз мой предыдущий комментарий. Особенно, слово "количество".

Comment: Извините, я не выспался, поэтому весь день зависаю. Спасибо за помощь.